# break-after:avoid; and break-before:avoid; not working

Tags: html, css

When the content of the table under the class="test1 clr" becomes too lengthy, it causes the entire table to move to the second page, resulting in excessive white space on the first page.

```html
<div class="test1 clr">I AM CLR</div>
                                                                                                                            <table  class="test2 table_type1 table_type_title">
                                                                            <colgroup>
                                                                                <col width="120">
                                                                                <col width=";">
                                                                            </colgroup>
                                                                            <tbody>
                                                                            <tr class =  "nb">
                                                                                <th>title</th>
                                                                                <td class="bb1">                                                                                
                                                                                        <span style="color: #ff6868; font-weight: bold;">[cancle]</span>                                                                                
                                                                                </td>
                                                                            </tr>
                                                                            <tr  id="doc_content">
                                                                                <td colspan="2" class="bt0">
                                                                                    <div class="edTable">
                                                                                        <div class="edTableIn bort">                                                                                
                                                                                        </div>
                                                                                    </div>
                                                                                </td>
                                                                            </tr>
                                                                            </tbody>
                                                                        </table>
```

```css
@media print {
.test1 {
        break-after: avoid !important;
        break-before : avoid !important;
    }
    .test2 {
        break-before: avoid !important;
        break-inside : auto !important;
    }

}
```

print result :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lp0XI.png)

I want to keep the table on the first page to eliminate excessive white space.

Like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5qdHT.png)

Comment: Please make a runnable snippet so we can see the problem. In particular what is any of the other CSS doing? See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example